# How to remove crb_carbon_fields_container_ from theme options permalink in Carbon fields

Tags: wordpress, plugins, carbon-fields

When I register theme options via Carbon fields plugin, then I see crb_carbon_fields_container include in the permalink.
I want to remove it.

```
function setting_page(){
    Container::make( 'theme_options', __( 'Theme Options' ) )
    ->add_fields( array(
        Field::make( 'text', 'crb_facebook_url', __( 'Facebook URL' ) ),
        Field::make( 'textarea', 'crb_footer_text', __( 'Footer Text' ) )
    ) );
}
add_action('carbon_fields_register_fields','setting_page');
```

Current Permalink: https://prnt.sc/21p595m

Expected Permalink: https://prnt.sc/21p5eit

Answer (score 0):

You can use `->set_page_file('url')` method on container.